# Replacing value in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column with values like this: ["Here"](http://%22http://web1.expandetunegocio.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/francisco-javier-aviles-montes-arquitecto-fundamenta-arquitectura-150x150.jpg%22)

I want to change the "web1.expandetunegocio" to "ce.expandetunegocio" so just change web1 to ce

**i have tried this query, but dont works:**

```
UPDATE 25v5U995_usermeta
SET meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value, 'web1', 'ce')
WHERE meta_key LIKE '%web1%'
```

Comment: column name is "meta_value"

Comment: Can you elaborate of "don't work"? Are you getting an error? The wrong result?

Comment: And "dont works" means what exactly? What error do you get?

Comment: i just get 0 affected fields message

Comment: If so, then obviously you do not have the data you expect in that table.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/f1dd62020e44a505ac533cc8f108dad1  here you can see the table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is use the right column in your `WHERE` condition

The following query should work in your case:

```
UPDATE 25v5U995_usermeta SET meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value, 'web1', 'ce') WHERE meta_value LIKE '%web1%'
```

Since the web1 substring exists in meta_value column, instead of meta_key column hence was unable to find the right row.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

I think your problem is that 'WHERE meta_key LIKE '%web1%'' don't get any result. Can you try to do a select?

```
 SELECT * FROM '25v5U995_usermeta' WHERE meta_key LIKE '%web1%'
```